# How to record video in iPhone using Objective-C?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, video

I have a map application in which there is a button named video. If a user clicks on the video button he can record video at any location he like and simultaneously play the video.

How can I do this? My code is as follows:

```
-(IBAction)video:(id)sender { UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init]; picker.delegate = self; NSArray *sourceTypes = [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:picker.sourceType]; if (![sourceTypes containsObject:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie ]){ NSLog(@"device not supported"); return; } picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera; picker.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObject:(NSString *)kUTTypeVideo]; picker.videoQuality = UIImagePickerControllerQualityTypeHigh; [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES]; }
```

Comment: Take a look at [Apple's guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/CameraAndPhotoLib_TopicsForIOS/Articles/TakingPicturesAndMovies.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010406-SW1). It should give you all the information you need. If you have any specific problem, you're welcome to ask here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Apple Programming guides](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AudioandVideoTechnologies/AudioandVideoTechnologies.html)

> Starting in iPhone OS 3.0, you can
>   record video, with included audio, on
>   supported devices. To display the
>   video recording interface, create and
>   push a UIImagePickerController object,
>   just as for displaying the
>   still-camera interface.
>
> To record video, you must first check that the camera source type
>   (UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera)
>   is available and that the movie media
>   type (kUTTypeMovie) is available for
>   the camera. Depending on the media
>   types you assign to the mediaTypes
>   property, the picker can directly
>   display the still camera or the video
>   camera, or a selection interface that
>   lets the user choose.
>
> Using the UIImagePickerControllerDelegate
>   protocol, register as a delegate of
>   the image picker. Your delegate object
>   receives a completed video recording
>   by way of the
>   imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:
>   method.
>
> On supported devices, you can also pick previously-recorded videos from a
>   user’s photo library.
>
> For more information on using the image picker class, see
>   UIImagePickerController Class
>   Reference. For information on trimming
>   recorded videos, see
>   UIVideoEditorController Class
>   Reference and
>   UIVideoEditorControllerDelegate
>   Protocol Reference.

Once you have the video in your UIImagePickerController delegate you can then save it to your app's documents directory using standard file operations.

Comment: actually when i click on the button of video my app crashes and in the nslog this error msg is written

Comment: Simulator does not have a camera. So u cannot test it. Use a device